# How can I eyeball a URL before clicking, on Brave on Android?

Tags: url, hyperlinks, brave-browser

On a desktop, I always hover and look at a link before clicking it.

Is there a way I can get Brave on Android to show me the link contents first?

Comment: What have you tried and what isn't working? Have you tried just long-pressing the link? It should show you the full link, plus give you options like Open in a new tab, private tab, copy link, share, etc...

Comment: That works on IOS as well.

Comment: @acejavelin.  that works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To inspect a link in most mobile browsers, as well as perform additional functions like copying or sharing the link, opening it in a new tab or a private window, copying the link text, and other functions common in desktop versions of browsers by right-clicking the link, you would long-press the link and that will bring up a menu as well as show the full link address in the pop-up.